# Why is my GCP function logging errors that should be info or debug?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I've got a python 3.7 google cloud function integrating with google storage and google logging, so I've deployed a key file with the function and reference it using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.  All works fine insomuch as my function does what it is supposed to and returns the proper outputs, etc., with the only caveat being that it is logging stuff at ERROR level that seem like they should be at INFO or lower.  Or... maybe I'm missing something, and I'd rather not be missing something here.

Bottom line: I want clean logs such that errors/warnings are meaningful and I don't have to deal with noise.

Here's an example of my log output:
[image]

You'll notice that I have my own logging appearing at the DEBUG level but right before and after it are seemingly innocuous log entries that are marked as ERROR.  (And, yes, I know my own log entry is appearing 2x, once at debug, once at info - that's another question but lower in priority for me.)

Is this just normal for google cloud functions, or is there something I could do to correct this?

**UPDATE:**

Here is how I configure logging in my python code:

```
import logging
import logging.config

import google.cloud.logging

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.get_default_handler()
client.setup_logging()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Now, I noticed in local debugging (using the functions-framework) that I was also getting these same messages output just to the console without any log entry metadata, so tracing thru the google client code I noticed that the client code is simply using the python logging libraries, and while they are outputting these messages at DEBUG they are somehow bypassing the google logging hooks that I expected to be getting used here.  Thus they are being output to stderr which of course google's logging interprets as an error.

This doesn't answer my own question so much as add some more context in hopes someone else has solved this.

**UPDATE #2 - an ugly solution that begs for a better one**

After doing some more digging through the google cloud client code, I have arrived at the answer, although I don't like it and don't like what I'm doing to "fix" this.

What's going on is that when the function is deployed and running in GCP, the python logging framework is somehow initialized with additional handlers.  After calling client.setup_logging() if I print out the handlers attached to the root logger, I see:

```
root handlers=[<StreamHandler (NOTSET)>, <StreamHandler (WARNING)>, <CloudLoggingHandler (NOTSET)>]
```

Next, just to make things more fun, when the setup_logging() is called, there are some "excluded loggers" hard-coded into the client code to exclude them from using the CloudLoggingHandler (with a comment stating that without doing that we'd see infinite recursion).  So anything logged using those google-specific loggers will always go to one or both of those StreamHandlers I captured above.

AND, the finale of explanation: the default stream used by StreamHandler is stderr, which is rightly (IMHO) interpreted by google's logging reporting as "error."

So with that explanation, I can at least hack around this with the following code in my own function class:

```
import logging
import google.cloud.logging

client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
client.setup_logging() # NOTE specifying logger_level here sets only the root logger which I'll reset below
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Now I must configure my individual loggers to allow for debug
_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

What this is doing is hiding the debug from those google loggers and then anything they would log at INFO or higher would still show up as errors (due to the stderr output), and then I must remember to configure my own loggers as DEBUG where I want that level of logging to take effect.

Now, why don't I like this?  Why am I not just answering my own question here?  Because this is a hacky solution requiring me to know the internals of google's client code and logging.  It is not intuitive and disallows me to use the root logger for defaults I want to cascade throughout the software.

Thus, I'd still like to see if there is a better solution that I'm missing, and so I'm leaving the question open.

Comment: Incidentally, in case it helps anyone, I was able to hack my way to a resolution for all of my python cloud function logging woes, and contain the hack in a util file to help it be minimally invasive to the code cloud function code.  See https://github.com/hamilton-scott-jason/cloud-function-logger.  I'd LOVE a better solution!

Comment: Unfortunately still an issue in February 2024. My workaround was to use a log format that GCP seems to parse more effectively.
With `logging.basicConfig` I am setting the log format to the following
```u'{"message": "%(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s", "severity": "%(levelname)s", "time": "%(asctime)s"}'
```

Answer (score 12):

You are right, log levels like warning and debug which should be painted as yellow and green entries are not respected when running the Cloud Logging client library from a Cloud Function.

I have found that this has been already reported to Google in this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/124403972).

Some of the most important points they have discussed are:

**Symptom**: There is no way to specify Stackdriver log severity from Cloud Functions without using the Stackdriver API. For example logging.debug('log debug'), logging.info('log info'), logging.warning('log warning'), logging.error('log error') and logging.critical('log critical') will all create Stackdriver logs with underpopulated severity entry.

**Answer:** Cloud Functions PM here. We're aware of the issue and working on a long term solution. We are also correcting the docs to note that writing to stdout/stderr does not change the severity level attached to logs that appear in Stackdriver Logging. The deployed logs won't have a severity attached.

It would be great if you could as well post your comments on the public issue tracker and rate the thread to increase its relevance.

Comment: Thank you - I really do appreciate the response and the issue tracker link.  I'm not going to mark this as the correct/accepted answer though, since it is not really resolving my question other than giving me comfort that it is a known issue.